# Why use the square function to construct a conformal mapping which maps the right half of the open unit disc onto the strip $ -1 < Re (z) < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've tried to construct a conformal mapping which maps the right half of the open unit disc onto the strip $-1 < Re (z) < 1$, and what I've come up with is:

$\frac {4i}{\pi} Log \left((-1-i)\frac{z + i} {z - i}\right)$

Hopefully this mapping does what it's supposed to do. Essentially I've just combined a simple Möbius transformation with the principle branch of the logarithm function.

However in a published sheet of solutions, also the square function is used:

$\frac {2i}{\pi} Log \left(i\left(\frac{z + i} {z - i}\right)^2\right)$

To use the square function here seems pointless, or am I missing something?

What the Möbius transformation $\frac {z + i} {z - i}$ does is mapping the right half of the open unit disc to the second quadrant. We want to make the image symmetric about the real axis, and we can do that by multiplying the transformation with a constant with the argument $(-3) × \frac {\pi} {4}$. Why square and multiply with a constant with the argument $\frac {\pi} {2}$ instead? The fact that squaring makes the image wider doesn't do things any simpler.

Next, if we use the principle branch of the logarithm function, the image gets transformed further to a horizontal strip, which we can rotate and scale to the desired vertical shape. The constant $\frac {4i} {\pi}$ is precisely what we need. As can be seen, $\frac {2i} {\pi}$ is used instead in the formula which involves a sqare.

Comment: After three years on this site you might want to start to format your math properly. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've formated my math now, which was a lot of hard work. Why isn't the interpretion of formulas automatic, like on Wolfram Alpha?